# Extracting column names for all files in a folder

Tags: r

I have a large number of .csv files, and I need to extract the column names for each file in a separate spreadsheet. To do this for a single file I use the code below.

```
class <- c(1,3,4)
zone <- c(5,2,3)
signal <- c(7,2,1)
df <- cbind(class,zone,signal)

     class zone signal
[1,]     1    5      7
[2,]     3    2      2
[3,]     4    3      1

data.frame(colnames(df))
```

I use the data.frame function so that when I export the results as a .csv the column names are in a single column (with the output below).

```
  colnames.df.
1        class
2         zone
3       signal
```

How can this function be applied to a folder so that I can generate a separate .csv files populated with column names for each of the original .csv files?

Comment: Use `list.files()` to get the csv you need in a list. Loop over that list, read the files and extract column names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to what @Sotos said :

List all the files, read them and extract the headers and write it as separate csv file for each file.

```
file_paths <- list.files('/path/to/csvfiles', full.names = TRUE)

lapply(file_paths, function(x) {
   header = colnames(read.csv(x, nrows = 1))
   write.csv(data.frame(column_name = header), 
             paste0(x, '_colname.csv'), row.names = FALSE)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do:

```r
#move to your respective directory
setwd('./directory_name')

#select csv files
csv_files = list.files(path = '.', pattern = '.csv$')

#use for loop to iterate through each file and store column names in a list.
col_names = list()
for(file in csv_files){
  df = read.csv(file)
  file_name = gsub('.csv$', '', file)
  col_names[[file_name]] = colnames(df)
}

col_names_df = stack(col_names) %>% setNames(., c('column_name', 'file_name'))
write.csv(col_names_df, 'column_names.csv')
```

Comment: Many thanks Monte, looking back on it I am wondering if there is a way to report all of the information in a single column, with the filename being the first entry followed by the column names?

Comment: Example? is it something like one row per file and columns or concatenating two columns `column_name and file_name`

Comment: One column containing all of the data. Example would be if there was a file with 3 column names the first row would the file_name.csv, and the following 3 rows would be populated with the column names, with the 5th row occupied by the Filename_2.csv and then the column names for that file